# Symfony, http-foundation and getAcceptableContentTypes()

Tags: symfony, request, content-type

I know i can set content types manually, how ever the array gets overwritten. i cannot append to it. Need help, please.

Result of calling the function

.CSS files are not going thro, ie. text/css.

Comment: array (size=4)
  0 => string 'text/html' (length=9)
  1 => string 'application/xhtml+xml' (length=21)
  2 => string 'application/xml' (length=15)
  3 => string '*/*' (length=3)

Comment: Accept 
text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Referer 
https://localhost/framework/

Comment: Request is trying to obtain .css but server is not serving it. I get The stylesheet https://localhost/public/css/style.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2017:19:34:13 +0300] "GET /framework/ HTTP/1.1" 200 644
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2017:19:34:13 +0300] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 644

Comment: html is presented like it should but .css file is not applying. When i go to the css file directly from address bar of the browser i get the normal html page as result, not the css file contents.